# How to get big record data from external API in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nusoap

I want to get 28,000 records data from external API.

For this, I use `nusoap_client`. However, when I test it I don't get any data and I don't get any error.

This is my function:

```
public function get_all(){
     $url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:xxx/services/Pending?wsdl";
     $client = new \nusoap_client($url, 'wsdl');

     $pDate = isset($_GET["Date"]) ? $_GET["Date"] : '26/2/2017 01:01:01';
     $operation = 'getPendingData';
     $param1 = array(
         'Date' => $Date,
     );
     $result = $client->call($operation, $param1);

     print_r($result);
     exit();
}
```

In the API I must get data starting from `26/02/2017 01:01:01`. When I test it I don't get any data. When I changed date to `27/02/2017 01:01:01` I got 759 records data.

How to fix this?

Comment: generally speaking , your soap call is working nice , i mean , it give data in some cases ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, yes in some cases i got the data, like, when i change date to `27/02/2017 01:01:01` , i got 759 records data. But only for date `26/02/2017 01:01:01`, i don't get any data. 

I have tested the API url using SOAPUI tools. In that tools, i got 28.000 records data for date `26/02/2017 01:01:01`, but when i am using code, i don't get any data

Comment: Maybe something with `$pDate !== $Date`?